# How to find the duration of a seasonal event?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

Forgive me for the lack of proper description; it has been many a year since I did any rigorous statistical analysis.
The basic problem I am looking to solve it how do I calculate the duration of an event that is happening seasonally in my data? The data I am working on is road inspections. They are carried out regularly, and I need to calculate how long each inspection takes. The only data I have is the amount of road inspected on each date. This is an example of what the data looks like:
[image: Inspection data]
I know how to use a correlogram to ascertain the period of the seasonality, but don't know the best approach to then find the 'duration' of each inspection (which is just the time between the date of the first inspection of that batch, and the final inspection).